# How to calculate difference between dates in R

Tags: r, date, subtraction

I am working on a project right now and encountered this problem.

I have a dataset consisting of two dates columns. One, say it x1, stands for check-in dates, the other, say it x2, stands for check-out dates.

Both of them are in the "year-month-day" format and have the type of string.

What I would like to do is figuring out how long does a person stay using check-in, check-out dates. I've tried multiple functions like as.Date. But all failed and I believe I just can't subtract these two dates directly as the results wouldn't represent the actual stay length.

Does anybody have any idea on how to do this in R?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried as.Date and converted them into Date object, and I used head() function to list some values from them. All of them returned "NA"

Comment: ok, I will try again. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's still not working. Is there anyway else to get the difference between two dates without using the Date object?

Comment: If the date format is the problem,  package `lubridate` has conversion methods that work with more formats, such as `ymd()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you want the difference between checkout and checkin? I would try this:

```
library(lubridate)
df<-data.frame(x1=c("2017-03-23","2017-03-24"),x2=c("2017-03-24","2017-03-28"))
df[]<-lapply(df,ymd)
df$x2-df$x1
```

Comment: Hey, this worked perfect! Thanks!